# appBundle in symfony 2.6

Tags: symfony, bundle

i would like to understand what is the role of AppBundle in symfony 2.6,it comes always when I create a new project..
Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's meant to be used for your application specific logic. This is one of Symfony's best practices (http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html).

These best practices are guidelines, not rules, so feel free to structure your code how you think/feel is best.

Comment: In other words: You put your website in that bundle and you can install 3rd party bundles using composer. Only when you want to override a 3th party bundle OR when you want to develop your own 3th party bundle you create an additional bundle. No hard rules but best practices like bfranco said